# Gitlab CI include is not triggering

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

Expecting:CI need to trigger build and test then it should scan for dependencies vulnerability

Current Behaviour CI trigger but only run build and test not running Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
    - build
    - test

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - echo "Building"

test:
    stage: test
    script:
        - echo "Testing"

include:
  - template: Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml
```

Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml can be found in the following URL
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Security/Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml

Comment: please include the content of `Dependency-Scanning.gitlab-ci.yml` too so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving it to the top of the file.  Works for me.

Can you toss the error in your post?  Are you getting something like this if you use the CI linter? https://gitlab.com/amishpanda/cheatsheet/-/ci/lint

```
Found errors in your .gitlab-ci.yml:

    dependency_scanning job: stage parameter should be .pre
    setup
    build
    .post

You can also test your .gitlab-ci.yml in CI Lint
```

Comment: I'm also trying to include the gitlab dependency scanning template and adding it to the top of the file did not work. Same error as above.